# How can I optimize this MYSQL query? (huge delay to obtain the result)

Tags: mysql

I have a Problem doing this particular query. I have tested and found that there is an enormous waste of time to obtain the query  because of those instructions that HAS "OR".

Please do not question the information that I need, that is not negotiable.
I tried to use the ALIAS ("Suma_Bondiolas s/hueso") named but I couldnt.

Thanks for your recomendations.

Here you have 3 things. 1) The photo of the query in Heidi. 2) The sql code. 3) The result of the query.

1) IMAGE OF CODE for faster comprehension.

[image]

2) CODE:

```
SELECT (ELT(WEEKDAY(fecha) + 1, 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado', 'Domingo')) AS Día_Semana
    ,fecha AS 'Fecha_Desposte'
    ,IFNULL(ROUND((
            SELECT sum(kilos) 
            FROM rindes 
            WHERE (producto = 1625 OR producto = 1725 OR producto = 1695 OR producto = 1732 OR producto = 2001 OR producto = 2201) 
            AND fecha=Fecha_Desposte
        ),2),0) AS 'Suma_Bondiolas s/hueso'
    ,IFNULL(ROUND((
            SELECT sum(kilos) 
            FROM rindes 
            WHERE (producto = 1427 OR producto = 1527 OR producto = 1695 OR producto = 1698) 
            AND fecha=Fecha_Desposte
        ),2),0) AS 'Suma_huesos_Bondiola'
    ,( SELECT sum(kilos) 
        FROM rindes 
        WHERE (producto = 1625 OR producto = 1725 OR producto = 1695 OR producto = 1732 OR producto = 2001 OR producto = 2201) 
        AND fecha=Fecha_Desposte
    )/(SELECT sum(kilos) 
        FROM rindes 
        WHERE (producto = 1427 OR producto = 1527 OR producto = 1695 OR producto = 1698) 
        AND fecha=Fecha_Desposte
    ) as 'Huesos Bondiola/Bondiolas sin huesos' 
FROM rindes 
WHERE fecha >='2018-10-29' AND fecha <= '2019-01-30' 
GROUP BY Fecha_Desposte 
ORDER BY Fecha_Desposte DESC
```

3) RESULT:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a candidate for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT `Dia_Semana`, `Fetcha_Deposte`
   , IFNULL(ROUND(`Suma_Bondiolas s/hueso`, 2), 0) AS `Suma_Bondiolas s/hueso`
   , IFNULL(ROUND(`Suma_huesos_Bondiola`, 2), 0) AS `Suma_huesos_Bondiola`
   , `Suma_Bondiolas s/hueso` / `Suma_huesos_Bondiola` AS `Huesos Bondiola/Bondiolas sin huesos`
FROM (
    SELECT ELT(WEEKDAY(fecha) + 1, 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado', 'Domingo') AS `Día_Semana`
     , fecha AS `Fecha_Desposte`
     , SUM(CASE WHEN producto IN (1625,1725,1695,1732,2001,2201) THEN kilos ELSE 0 END) AS `Suma_Bondiolas s/hueso`
     , SUM(CASE WHEN producto IN (1427,1527,1695,1698) THEN kilos ELSE 0 END) AS `Suma_huesos_Bondiola`
    FROM rindes 
    WHERE fecha >='2018-10-29' AND fecha <= '2019-01-30' 
    GROUP BY Fecha_Desposte, `Día_Semana`
) AS subQ
ORDER BY Fecha_Desposte DESC
;
```

Note the subquery format of this was not strictly necessary, but it prevents having to duplicate the first two sum expressions for the final column.

Also, if the product id values used are a small subset of the data, adding `AND producto IN ([all product ids in both sum expressions])` to subQ's WHERE could speed things up too. I've heard more recent version of MySQL have optimized the `IN` operator a bit, but I'm not sure if it can take advantage of indexes now; but it would be worth trying to index `(fecha, producto)` if you add the condition.